# online server can not discover jpeg image type while localhost does

Tags: php, jpeg, image-uploading, file-type

i'm using a simple script to upload and resize uploaded images while preserving transparency the problem is the server doesn't recognize jpeg images while localhost does here's the code

```
function image_resize($src, $dst, $width, $height, $crop=0){

if(!list($w, $h) = getimagesize($src)) return "Unsupported picture type 1!";

$type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($src,"."),1));
if($type == 'jpeg') { $type = 'jpg'; }
switch($type){
case 'bmp': $img = imagecreatefromwbmp($src); break;
case 'gif': $img = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;
case 'jpg': $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
case 'png': $img = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;
default : return "Unsupported picture type 2!";
}

$new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// preserve transparency
if($type == "gif" or $type == "png"){
imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($new, false);
imagesavealpha($new, true);
}

imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

switch($type){
case 'bmp': imagewbmp($new, $dst); break;
case 'gif': imagegif($new, $dst); break;
case 'jpg': imagejpeg($new, $dst); break;
case 'png': imagepng($new, $dst); break;
}
return true;
}
```

and here's the upload code

```
require('_req/func.php');       
$img_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['main_img']['name']);
if(strstr($img_name," ")){
$img_name = str_replace(" ","_",$img_name); 
}
$num = substr(md5(mt_rand(1,999999)),0,4);
$new_name = $num.$img_name;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['main_img']['tmp_name'], "../products_large/".$new_name);
$pic_type = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['main_img']['name'],"."));
$pic_name = "../products_large/".$new_name;

if (true !== ($pic_error = @image_resize($pic_name, "../products_thumb/".$new_name, 180, 180, 1))) {
echo $pic_error;
unlink($pic_name);
 }
    else {
require_once('_req/base.php');
$addNameQ = "update products set Product_Img = '$new_name' where Product_ID = '$id'";
$addNameR = mysql_query($addNameQ);
mysql_close($connect);
}
```

and the error i get is

```
Unsupported picture type 2!
```

which is in line 10 of the function code but the localhost can upload the same image without any problem and when returning $_FILES["main_img"]["type"] i get image/jpeg. 
Any ideas please ?

Comment: Is the local server based on Windows and the remote on Unix/Linux? If so, please think about case sensitivity in the extensions of the file attributes

Comment: the extension is jpg in lowercase

Comment: Can you do an echo of the type variable in order to verify what has been parsed to the server?

Comment: that's weird it doesn't return the image type

Comment: Maybe you would be good to add some kind of error handling in your code. Take a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Maybe you exceed the file size limit of your hoster? Would be good to know the error code

Comment: if ($_FILES["main_img"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["main_img"]["error"];
    }
it doesn't return any errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     $type = strtolower(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

You can also store the pic type like this (But you don't use it anyway)

```
$pic_type = ["main_img"]["type"]
```

Comment: it doesn't return an error but the image is not uploaded and the page doesn't get any data after refresh the only change is the error doesn't show up

Comment: What is the output of the $type now?

Comment: it doesn't echo anything i've ried to echo it different places in the function file but nothing at all

Comment: $_FILES["main_img"]["type") returns image/jpeg

Comment: THat's the way the file type is being returned but you don't use it anyway do you? With your code you could also upload a move / executable and simply name it .jpg as you don't do any file type checks

Comment: extension is already jpg here's the image name  nokia-lumia-925-1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

the problem was using mysql_real_escape_string before opening the connection to the database and it should be used after opening the connection